# Saving objects in android

Tags: java, android, serialization

Im a newbie developer and I want to know how to save an ArrayList of non-Serializable objects into a file in android external storage?

Or is there a better way to store objects in external storage and use them later?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gson in order to serialize objects of classes (if this is what you want to do). Then you can store the objects within the [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) or the [Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). 
If you explicitly want to store the objects in the external storage, you could use text files.
See the [Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) for examples.

If this is not what you're trying to do, please define "objects". :)